# How to open explore directory using Angular?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

How to open explore directory using Angular clicking over DOM element, not input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what you would need to do.

#### HTML

```
<div (click)="openInput()">CLICK ME</div>
<input style="visibility: hidden;" type="file" #inputElement />
```

#### COMPONENT

```js
class MyComponent {
    @ViewChild('inputElement', {static: false}) el: ElementRef;

    openInput() {
        this.el.nativeElement.click();
    }
}
```

This would allow you to open an input element by clicking that div.

DOM access is not discouraged anymore by the angular team so you would not need to use `Renderer2`

Cheers